# django read file for importing details

Tags: python, django, csv, django-adaptors

I have used `django-adaptops` for this purpose. i have implemented the mechanism shown in docs. I need to know how can achieve this using browser , for example - i have a template where user has the option to select the csv file, once i click the import button i get the call to my view , but here i cannot read the file to upload to my model. how i can perform this.

this is my template code.

```
 <form action="/manage/dashboard/importProspects" method="post" class="form-horizontal"
                      enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}

                    <div class="row-fluid" style="margin-top: 5%">
                        <div class="span6">
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <p>{{ csvform.fname.label_tag }} {{ csvform.fname }} {{ csvform.fname.url }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-success " style="margin-left:10px; ">
                            Import from CSV
                        </button>
                    </div>
       </form>
```

`csvForm` is form object passed when this template is loaded.

the form code is below:

```
class ImportCsvForm(forms.Form):
     fname = forms.FileField(label='CSV')
```

and `/manage/dashboard/importProspects` url will call my view `importcsv` which right now does not perform anything.

how can i handle this so that i can read the csv file, i cannot get the csvfile path. or am i missing some thing here ? please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this,

**in template:**

```
<form action="/manage/dashboard/importProspects" method="post" class="form-horizontal"
                      enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}

                    <div class="row-fluid" style="margin-top: 5%">
                        <div class="span6">
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <p>
                                    <input type="file" name="csvfile" />
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-success " style="margin-left:10px; " />

                    </div>
   </form>
```

**in urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns("mine.views",
        url(r'^', 'csvupload'),)
```

**in views.py file:**

```
def csvupload(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       f = request.FILES['csvfile']
       with open("/tmp/csvfile.csv", 'wb+') as destination:
                for chunk in f.chunks():
                    destination.write(chunk)
```

then use csvfile whatever you want.....Hope this helps to you.

Comment: thanks , worked great , i almost got into the same solution , but the difference was i was always uploading and storing in db. well this seems to be simpler solution.